# Why $rotation variable in scss not parse in filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage

Tags: css, sass

Compiled css

```
.fa-rotate-90 {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=$rotation);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg); }
```

SCSS

```
$fa-css-prefix : 'fa';
@mixin fa-icon-rotate($degrees, $rotation) {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=$rotation);
  -webkit-transform: rotate($degrees);
     -moz-transform: rotate($degrees);
      -ms-transform: rotate($degrees);
       -o-transform: rotate($degrees);
          transform: rotate($degrees);
}

.#{$fa-css-prefix}-rotate-90  { @include fa-icon-rotate(90deg, 1);  }
```

Why I got unexpected result `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=$rotation);`

Can anyone please point out what mistake in this scss.

Comment: You have to use interpolation - `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=#{$rotation})`.

Comment: @Harry it's working

Comment: @Harry put as a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I had mentioned earlier in comments, for this case we need to make use of interpolation like in the below code block to get the value of the `$rotation` variable printed. The syntax for [interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) is `#{$var}`. Interpolation is required because the variable's value needs to be placed within another string and then the whole thing needs to be assigned as the value to a property.

```
$fa-css-prefix : 'fa';
@mixin fa-icon-rotate($degrees, $rotation) {
             filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=#{$rotation});
  -webkit-transform: rotate($degrees);
     -moz-transform: rotate($degrees);
      -ms-transform: rotate($degrees);
       -o-transform: rotate($degrees);
          transform: rotate($degrees);
}

.#{$fa-css-prefix}-rotate-90  { @include fa-icon-rotate(90deg, 1);  }
```